# Executing a loading button for a few seconds

Tags: button, loading

i desgined a loading button by myself. If a user clicks on a button, the loading button shall be displayed for a few seconds and then shall be no more displayed until the button is clicked again.

This code shows an example of the working principle.

HTML:

```
<div id="loader" style="display:none"></div>
<button class="button" onclick="load()">Loading Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
```

JS

```
function load() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(stop(), 5000)
}

function stop() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
}
```

I have the problem that the loading button is not invoked, but is never shown. I guess this is because the elements on the page are refreshed after the js functions are run through, so that only the last command regarding the "loader"-ID is taken care of.

Does anyone know a way of considering also the first command?

Thanks for your help,

Boesinga

Answer (score 1):

```
function load() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(stop(), 5000)
}
```

the problem is that setTimeout will invoke the stop function immediately and your loader will be never shown.

```
function load() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none"; }, 3000);
}
```

in this case you can call only one function and this will work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-yyokfc?file=index.html
**working example**

If you are using XMLHttpRequest set style.display = "block" to the spinner to be his default state and in the request function call the stop function

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', "" true);
 // This will be called after the response is received
    request.onload = function () {
      // stop spinner
         stop();
     // do stuff

    }
    request.send();
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to "force" the invoking of the loader? Actually, I am using the setTimout only as an example. In reality I am using a XMLHttpRequest to GET some data. This also takes some seconds.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. Sadly, it still doesn't work. The loading button changes its visibility after the requests are finished and not during the downloading of the data. I also tried to set the display setting of the loading button depending on the readyState of the XMLHttpRequest, but it doesn't change anything.